# RxJava zip with empty list of observables

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

Based on post type i need to push item to observable list. So in case when `if` closure is not used (for example `post.type != SomeType`) my observable list is empty.

So due to that im receiving `NoSuchElementException` all the time from `Single.zip`

***Here is my sample code***

```
val observableList = mutableListOf<Single<Response>>()

if (post.type == SomeType) {
      observableList.add(addNewObservable()) <-- adding API call to the lsit
}

return Single.zip(observableList) { arg -> arg } <-- Throws error NoSuchElementException
```

I figured that i can use for `post type != SomeType` :

```
observableList.add(Single.just(Response(""))
```

And this will work fine.

So is there a better solution for it? How can i avoid that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list can legitimately be empty, maybe you want a [`Maybe`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html) instead of `Single`. One way would be

```
val observableList = mutableListOf<Maybe<Response>>()
...
if (post.type == SomeType) {
      observableList.add(addNewObservable().toMaybe())
}
...
return Maybe.zip(observableList) { arg -> arg }
```

`Maybe.zip` on an empty list should return a `Maybe` which completes immediately without emitting anything.

Or an alternate solution: just test if the list is empty before calling `Single.zip`.

It really depends on what behavior you want (except for not throwing an exception) in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a check for emptiness beforehand. This can be done for an Observable or a Single.

```
public Observable<String> zipObservable(List<Observable<String>> strings) {
    return strings.isEmpty()
        ? Observable.just("empty")
        : Observable
           .zip(strings, objects -> "non-empty");
}

public Single<String> zipSingle(List<Single<String>> strings) {
    return strings.isEmpty()
        ? Single.just("empty")
        : Single
           .zip(strings, objects -> "non-empty");
}
```